# Proof Check for Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Admittedly, my proof is very ugly. You can skip Lemma 2 and 3 really. I just put them there for my own benefit. It's really a combination of Lemma 1 and the theorem itself. Anyway it's a bit long and clunky but I'd appreciate any feedback. I wanted to be sure that nothing was invalid as I haven't seen this proof before. Here is the link:

[Fermat's Little Theorem](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzAdlbUKESH5Ym9yWGxqYXVfc2M/edit)

Comment: You could just post it here, using LaTex.

Comment: I tried! If you click the link you'll see that I'm not very good at Latex. I tried to copy paste into the text field on the webpage but it was a big mess so I thought it would be easier for me to just post a link. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of lemma 2 is pretty ugly to my eyes. The definition I like for $a \equiv  b \bmod n$ is that $n$ divides $b - a$. So to prove that $an + b \equiv b \bmod n$, you look at $b - (an + b) = -an$, which is evidently divisible by $n$, and you're done. I think you can similarly simplify Lemma 3.

POST-COMMENT additions:
I went and looked at the proof itself. The gist is this:

1. Every number $a$ is congruent, mod $p$, to a number $r$ between $0$ and $p-1$.
2. Such numbers all satisfy $r^p \equiv r \bmod p$.
3. By transitivity of congruence, $a^p \equiv a \bmod p$.

The meat of the proof is in step 2, of course.

If you shuffle things around to use my version of congruence, the proof of part 2 gets a good deal shorter and simpler, I believe. It looks like this:

We claim that $r^p \equiv r \bmod p$ for $0 \le r \le p-1$. The proof is by induction. The cases $r = 0, 1$ are trivial. Now suppose we have some $r$ with $0 \le r \le p-1$, and that the claim is true for all $m$ with $0 \le m < r$. Taking $m = r-1$, we have
\begin{align}
r^p - r &= (m + 1)^p - (m+1) \\
&= \left( \sum_{i=0}^p \binom{p}{i} m^{p-i} 1^i \right)  - (m + 1)\\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i} m^{p-i}  \right) +m^p + 1^p - m - 1\\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i} m^{p-i}  \right) +m^p - m
\end{align}
Each combinatorial coefficient in the sum is a multiple $k_i p$ for some integer $k_i$, by the lemma, so we have
\begin{align}
r^p - r 
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} p k_i m^{p-i} \right) +m^p - m \\
&= p\left( \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k_i m^{p-i} \right) +m^p - m \\
&\equiv m^p - m  \bmod p\\
&\equiv (r-1)^p - r  \bmod p\text{, by the choice of $m$} \\
&\equiv 0  \bmod p\text{, by the inductive hypothesis.} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm a little confused though. Lemma 2 was meant to prove that $an+b$ (mod n) $= b$ (mod n) rather than $an+b=b$ (mod n). Also I'm really not too familiar with number theory so I've never seen that definition of $a=b$ (mod n). I was just told a is then the remainder from Euclidean division. In any case thank you! But I was really wondering if my proof of Fermat's Theorem was valid. Thanks again!

Comment: @Thomas I think your notation is a bit confused. When talking about modular arithmetic, we generally use $\equiv$ instead of $=$. Also, the (mod $n$) part of the equation is a modifier of the whole equation, not just the right-hand or left-hand side.

Comment: @Joey Hi thanks for the comment! I understand a little about the congruence relation. There I get that $a \equiv b$ (mod n) $\Rightarrow n \vert a-b$. I thought of writing Lemma 2 in terms of congruence relations but I opted for equality because I thought it would fit my Fermat proof a little better. Oh! okay that clears things up, I thought the for $a=b$ (mod n), (mod n) was a mapping from $\mathbb{Z}$ into the set of the remainders, where $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and a is in the set of remainders. Thanks for clearing up the confusion!

Comment: Ah...I see. Thomas is thinking of a function $f : \mathbb Z \to \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ that takes a number, $k$, and produces its (positive) remainder, $f(k)$ upon division by $n$. That's called `mod(k, n)` in many programming languages. But mathematicians define something different: they say that $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod $n$ (written $a \equiv b \bmod n$) whenever $f(a) = f(b)$, but without ever computing $f(a)$ or $f(b)$. That turns out to be much more useful in most number theory applications.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Woah what a help! Actually though I think if I just make some notational modifications I can still save this proof. I think the concepts still might work. I'll come back with some revisions! Thanks again!

Comment: See further comments. Oops. I appear to have jumped the gun, and should have let you rewrite it...sorry. Notice that I don't need to use strong induction (i.e., that the hypothesis works for all $m$ less than $r$); it suffices to use it for just $m = r-1$. By the way, I like this proof a good deal, since it has an almost constructive feel to it.

Comment: @John If I could give you an upvote for your response, I would!Thank you so much! I appreciate the effort!